Правильно ли здесь написано: как стояло так и стоит?
Я почти все способы перепробовал, а задание как стояло так и стоит

Есть ли здесь ошибка? Если есть, то каким правилом нужно руководствоваться?

Ильнур, вы так и не отдали ни одного голоса (стрелочки вверх) за полезные ответы на свои вопросы. Также это касается любых ответов и вопросов, которые вас заинтересовали и внесли вклад в ваше образование.

КАК... ТАК И, союз

Запятая ставится только перед второй частью союза (перед словом
«так»).
Глянул дядя Зуй и как стоял, так и сел в снег.

Ошибка - отсутствие запятой перед второй частью союза.
Надо:
Я почти все способы перепробовал, а задание как стояло (на месте), так и стоит.

@ИльнурГайбдуллин Теперь у Вас появилась возможность не только принимать галочкой один из ответов на свой вопрос, но и отмечать любой ответ или вопрос стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх.
